# How can I populate a dropdown list in an infowindow (Google Maps API v3)?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, domready

I have two arrays: one for article names, and the other for url links to each article. I am trying to populate a dropdown list within an infowindow with the article names, linking to each article when selected.

It seems as if the links may have to do with using the `onchange` event, and otherwise I am using the `"domready" eventListener` to access the `<select>` elements' id tag.

Here is the relevant code I have so far, which is **not** working:

```
function setDropDownList(mapMarker, names, links)
{
    // event listener for dropdown list in the map markers' infowindow
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, "domready", function()
    {
        var articles = document.getElementById("select");

        var nextArticle, nextOption;

        for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            nextArticle = names[i];
            nextOption = new Option(nextArticle);

            /* add the new option to the option list
             ("null" for IE5, "-1" for all other browsers) */
            try
            {
                articles.add(nextOption, -1);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                articles.add(nextOption, null);
            }
        }
    });
} // end of function setDropDownList
```

Comment: ...I've just tried this with `addDomListener` instead of `addListener`, also with no avail...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I am calling the setDropDownList function after the marker is placed, I removed that listener and added one to display the infowindow when the marker is clicked.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/10/

It's up to you how to handle the onchange event when a selection is made. Right now, it alerts with a message and a dummy link.

```
function setDropDownList(mapMarker, mapInfoWindow, names, links)
{

        var articles = document.getElementById("select");
        articles.onchange = function() {
          alert("Going to link " + links[this.options.selectedIndex]);
        };
        var nextArticle, nextOption;

        for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            nextArticle = names[i];
            nextOption = new Option(nextArticle);

            /* add the new option to the option list
             ("null" for IE5, "-1" for all other browsers) */
            try
            {
                articles.add(nextOption, -1);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                articles.add(nextOption, null);
            }
            mapInfoWindow.setContent(document.getElementById("select"));

            google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, 'click', function() {
              mapInfoWindow.open(map, this);
            });
    }
} // end of function setDropDownList
```

I should add that `map` is global.

```
  var map;
  var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var mymarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map:map,
      position:new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)
    });

    var mynames = ["-- Choose an article --", "How to Launch a Fireball", "The Trinity of Magic", "Defending Against the Hax"];
var mylinks = ["to current page itself #", "http://fireball", "http://trinity", "http://hax"];

    var myinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    setDropDownList(mymarker, myinfowindow, mynames, mylinks);
  }
```

Comment: This is awesome, works perfectly, thanks @Lilina! I would give you +10 if this thing would let me... So, my confusion with whether to use the `"domready"` eventListener or not was because I wanted the option list to be created in the `content` attribute of the `infowindow` (*with* an id tag), and not in html. "domready" was not working for this, so I opted for a different solution -- just to set the content attribute with a string of html tags for the option list (see below).

Comment: You're right, it is better not to have the `select` defined in the html (it seems like it jumps from the HTML to the infowindow when `setContent` is called). My general policy is to solve the problem/answer question by changing the least amount of original code, so I silently left the `select` in the HTML alone. If you can manage to define a string with just the `select` and `options`, inside the script, and pass that to `setContent`, it would be the best, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, which for in my situation required that I create the entire options list within the `content` attribute of the infowindow, instead of within html.
So, instead of referring to the `id` of an html select element, I simply concatenate the options list as a String, looping through for each option addition (*I still don't understand the `"domready"` eventListener, as it was not working for this approach*).
I didn't get to use @Lilina's elegant `.onchange = function(){...` for the links, but instead used `window.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`, setting the value attribute of each option equal to its' url link.
Here's the code:

```
function setDropDownList(mapRef, mapMarker, markerInfoWindow, names, links)
{
    var articles = markerInfoWindow.content;
    articles += "<select onchange = \"window.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;\">";
    articles += "<option>&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;select an article&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;</option>";



    var nextArticle, nextArticleLink;

    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
        nextArticle = names[i];
        nextArticleLink = links[i];

        articles += "<option value = " + nextArticleLink + ">" + nextArticle + "</option>";

        // setting each info window for each map marker with the function below
        setInfoWindow(mapRef, mapMarker, markerInfoWindow);
    }



    articles += "</select>";
    markerInfoWindow.setContent(articles);
} // end of function setDropDownList
```